# ModelMapper not working mapping Entity to DTO

Tags: java, type-conversion, mapping, lombok, modelmapper

I am trying to convert an Entity to a DTO using ModelMapper and when mapping the properties are always to null, when the Entity is returning the values correctly:

Entity:

```
package org.example.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Table(name= "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String password;
}
```

Dto:

```
package org.example.dto;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
}
```

Service where mapping is done:

```
package org.example.services;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.example.dto.UserDto;
import org.example.model.User;
import org.example.repository.UserRepository;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Objects;

@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public UserDto getUser(Long id) throws Exception {
        var res = userRepository.findById(id);
        if(res.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("No existe el usuario con id=" + id);
        }
        log.info("Se ha devuelto el usuario: " + res.get());
        return mapper.map(res.get(), UserDto.class);
    }
```

I use lombok, but as far as I know this should not be a problem. The configuration is as follows:

```
package org.example.config;

import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.convention.MatchingStrategies;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AcmeConfig {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The truth is that I have always been able to map directly without problems since the process is very simple but for this project it does not work for me and it is quite frustrating.

I have tried several times to change the configuration, change the lombok annotations to manual getters/setters, but I have not obtained any change.